# How to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Profiler

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL Server Management Studio doesn't have it on the Tools menu in my case, as is reported in some blogs and forums. Apparently you somehow either got it or not, but how did you get it, if you did, is a luck of the draw, or something? I am a MSDN Subscriber.

Is is possible to install the Profiler using some well-defined steps? Like download X, press menu item Y and click button Z sort of prescription?

**[Edit additional info]**
Upgrading from SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition to Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition didn't help (previously, of 2008 R2 editions I had only Express Edition). I am trying Setup program's various options but am unable to upgrade from Basic Tools (originally installed with 2008 R2 Express Edition) to Complete Tools, which I hope would contain the Profiler. Complete Tools option can't be checked in any variation of Setup options that I am trying.

Answer (score 8):

if you allready have a setup of MS SQL Server 2008 R2, try to uninstall the tools only:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=UNINSTALL /FEATURES=TOOLS /QUIETSIMPLE
```

And the install it again:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=TOOLS /QUIETSIMPLE /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me.  I still only have the Data Profile Viewer.

Answer (score 4):

See the below screenshot.  You need to ensure that you have **Management Tools - Complete** checked when you install the Shared Features:

[image]

Likewise, see [this link on an explanation between Basic Management Tools and Complete Management Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-server-2008-management-tools-basic-vs-complete-explained).

Comment: I found that blog entry too but I can't get Management Tools Complete check box enabled. Setup program suggests that parent feature (Basic Tools I guess) was installed  for a different version (in my case it would be Express Edition) and to upgrade that version, but I already did upgrade from Express to Enterprise.

Comment: Ultimately I took the risk and decided to start uninstalling all SQL Server versions on my machine. In the process I was offered the option to uninstall only the Shared components. I did that and then installed them from scratch. This is about 2 hours process (SQL Server Installer is doing something for a long time, both during uninstall and subsequent install).
In the end the option to select Complete Tools was enabled and I got Profiler on Tools menu.

Comment: @Tony I have heard of that before, I believe.  I'm glad you got it working now.

Answer (score 3):

It is found on the Tools menu in SQL Server Management Studio, but is not installed as part of the Express edition.

You can check the version of SQL Server that you are running with:

```
USE master
GO
SELECT @@VERSION
GO
```

Comment: Using this query I see that I connect to both **Microsoft SQL Server 2005** - 9.00.3077.00 (X64)   Dec 17 2008 20:40:08 **Enterprise Edition** (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) and **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)** - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  **Express Edition** with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor).
In neither case do I get Profiler on my Tools menu. So you are saying that the 2008 R2 server must be upgraded from Express Edition.

Comment: Ok, obviously I wouldn't except the Express edition to include Profiler, but do you have a local install of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 as well? Is the profiler available in the start menu for 2005?

Comment: Yes and no. Possibly Profiler didn't exist in 2005? Anyway I am going to install 2008 R2 Developer Edition.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no better once I upgraded Enterprise 2005 to Enterprise 2008 R2. Right now I have **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)** - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  **Enterprise Edition (64-bit)** on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) 
but still no Profiler on Tools menu. Searching folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" I see Profiler folder and some files like "Default Profiler Trace.sql" but no executable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to completely uninstall the SQL 2008 R2 tools, then reinstall them from the SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition media.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem followed the above suggestions in this way:

I downloaded a trial edition of SQL server 2008 R2 - getting just a zip file named SQLFULL_x64_ENU.exe

Having downloaded and extracted this locally I ran the setup.exe which got me as far as mentioned above in that the Complete management tools option was grayed out.

I then ran the first cmd line listed above by Alex_L, using the location where my existing SQL Server 2008 R2 Advanced edition was already installed.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Release\setup.exe

Running this command took no time at all but no error messages were displayed so I carried on.

I then ran the second cmd line but used the folder where I had extracted the Full edition.
This took quite a while with a few dialogues displayed but which did not allow or ask for any manual input.

Once that was done (no error messages were reported ) I then ran SQL Server Mgt Studio using the program link which was already there, and voila, I now have Profiler on my Tools menu.

Remains to be seen if there are any unexpected consequences of this update........